# How to sort in Linq C#?

Tags: c#, sorting, linq-to-sql

I encountered a ridiculous problem using Linq into C# with my database included.

I tried so hard to sort by the name who got the higher rank of occurence.
Such as  :

Toto : 1 occurence.
Titi : 3 occurences.

fonction.

consolewriteLine(the one who got the higher score of occurences )

So, it will be Titi.

But now in Linq, this is my code :

```
public static void AfficherLePrenomMasculinLePlusFrequentParmiLesElus()
{
    using (var context = new electionEDM3())
    {
        var queryPrenomMasculin = from listedesprenomsM in context.Candidat
                                  where listedesprenomsM.sexe == "M"
                                  select listedesprenomsM;

        var prenomMasculinTrouve = from prenommasculintrouve in queryPrenomMasculin
                                   orderby prenommasculintrouve.prenom
                                   group prenommasculintrouve by prenommasculintrouve.prenom into nombredeprenommasculintrouve
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       prenom = nombredeprenommasculintrouve.Key,
                                       count = nombredeprenommasculintrouve.Count()
                                   };
        foreach (var PrenomMPlusSouventPresent in prenomMasculinTrouve)
        {
            int i = 0;
            int BestPrenomM = 0;
            string MeilleurPrenomMasculin = "";
            if ( PrenomMPlusSouventPresent.count > BestPrenomM)
            {
                BestPrenomM = PrenomMPlusSouventPresent.count;
                MeilleurPrenomMasculin = PrenomMPlusSouventPresent.prenom;
                BestPrenomM++;  
            }

            Console.WriteLine(BestPrenomM);
        }
    }
}
```

As a result, i only got all the occurences of the " Prenom ". And not the one who got the higher score.

What should i do ?

Thank for your answers !

Comment: You mean `orderby`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think it is `commandé par`

Comment: the first thing you should do is change the title of the question to match your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `order by` in your initial grouping is unnecessary.
Get the grouping first, then order by `count` descending, and take the first value. That should be the result you need.

Answer (score 2):

you are ordering using `prenommasculintrouve.prenom` and **after that** you are grouping, that is useless. You should order the result of the grouped data, using the `count` property of your anonymous type (`prenom`, `count` properties)

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a simple example

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string Sex { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
    private static void Linq2()
    {
        var namesList = new List<Person>();
        namesList.Add(new Person() { Sex = "M", name = "Jonh" });
        namesList.Add(new Person() { Sex = "M", name = "James" });
        namesList.Add(new Person() { Sex = "F", name = "Maria" });
        namesList.Add(new Person() { Sex = "F", name = "Cindy" });
        namesList.Add(new Person() { Sex = "M", name = "Jim" });
        namesList.Add(new Person() { Sex = "F", name = "Helen" });
        namesList.Add(new Person() { Sex = "M", name = "Jonh" });
        namesList.Add(new Person() { Sex = "F", name = "Maria" });
        namesList.Add(new Person() { Sex = "F", name = "Cindy" });
        namesList.Add(new Person() { Sex = "M", name = "Jonh" });

        var grouped = from personItem in namesList
                      group personItem by personItem.name into personGroup
                      select new
                      {
                          name = personGroup.Key,
                          count = personGroup.Count()
                      };
        // here you order your list Descending in order the name 
        // with the most Ocurrance will be on the top and select the First
        var nameMaxOcurrance = grouped.OrderByDescending(x => x.count).First().name;
        var maxOcurrance = grouped.Max(x => x.count);
        Console.WriteLine("Name with Max Ocurrances:" + nameMaxOcurrance);
        Console.WriteLine("Max Ocurrances:" + maxOcurrance);
    }
```

In your case

```
        var nameMaxOcurrance =  prenomMasculinTrouve.OrderByDescending(x => x.count).First().prenom;
        var maxOcurrances = prenomMasculinTrouve.Max(x => x.count);
```

Comment: Nice effort, should work (haven't tested), I would encourage for future answers trying to point out also the cause, so the OP could improve his/her code based on knowledge.